# Service Fabric Explorer: Limit Access to Single Applications

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there the possibility to limit the access to Service Fabric Explorer to certain services or specific users?

We have a scenario where we host multiple services on the same cluster. The log information of the Explorer shall be only visible for the 'owner' of each service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

> You can use access control to limit access to certain cluster
>   operations for different groups of users. This helps make the cluster
>   more secure. Two access control types are supported for clients that
>   connect to a cluster: Administrator role and User role.
>
> Users who are assigned the Administrator role have full access to
>   management capabilities, including read and write capabilities. Users
>   who are assigned the User role, by default, have only read access to
>   management capabilities (for example, query capabilities). They also
>   can resolve applications and services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security#role-based-access-control-rbac
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-roles

You can assign different roles to groups, but you cannot scope a role to a service, so basically its all or nothing, you cannot give granular control